# How to load local file in new tab?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angularjs java project. I won't to load local files of all file types (txt, pdf, image files etc.) from my system into new tab on click of button using javascript, angularjs or java code.

I able to load the content of the files but it is not displayed in correct format ie. I won't to load the file in similar format as they are placed on my system.

I would be thankful if anyone could help me in finding the solution.

Comment: Can you give an example of a file (and its type) that is not displaying as you'd expect?

Comment: File I tried to load was of (.txt) and it contains some lines which were displayed in <ul><li> format but all of its content was displayed in continos line.

Comment: A browser will not render a .txt file as HTML. If the .txt file is all one line, it will display as all one line.

Comment: But i won't to load the file in similar format as it gets open when i directly view the file in browser from my system ie. file contains path : - 
file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/20150202/1.txt

Comment: You need to stream the file from local to the front end. And you can open in a new tab as the file. But it depends on the file type whether the file will open in browser or it will it download. For example, txt and pdf will open in Chrome, it doc file will b downloaded. Different for different broswers. That's  the good way to show a file as it is. Or you will need to add more HTML codes based on file. Too complicated it will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply expect your browser to display the file as it is displayed in your local system.

If you try uploading a file and then viewing it, the browser will download the file and technically, you then view the file locally.

There are a few Cloud Storage options such as Box.com and Google Docs that have their own file explorer (that support limited file types). I don't think there is any free library available that does that as it requires quite an effort to support many file types for display in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can be achieved by following directive `ng-bind-html` in angular Js .
Kindly refer the examples and documentation which is given in Angular Js website

$sce is a service that provides Strict Contextual Escaping services to AngularJS.

[Check this link for directive documentaion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

For viewing pdf use `ng-pdfviewer`, include ng-pdfviewer.js as JavaScript file, along with pdf.js and pdf.compat.js.

Declare ngPDFViewer as dependency to your module.

You can now use the pdfviewer tag in your HTML source.

[Click here for GitHub link for ng-pdfviewer](https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer)

Use `<img ng-src="image.jpg"/>` for images

Comment: Thanks for your solution but by this my problem of opening all type of file didn't get solve.. I am not able to open pdfs, images etc.